# How to get Merge Push Subscription status?

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have Merge replication setup with Push subscriptions.
I read the following article: [Implementing a replication agent progress bar](http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/implementing-a-replication-agent-progess-bar/)
It is working fine if I initiate the agent from the subscriber, but the Status event of the MergeSynchronizationAgent Class is showing only status updates for the sessions that the client has initiated!
In short: I am looking for the same behavior that the default replication windows shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote that post to demonstrate how to synchronize a Merge Pull subscriptions using RMO, handling the MergeSynchronizationAgent Status Event to implement a progress bar with agent status messages.

To get this working with Merge Push subscriptions, you will need to utilize the [MergeSubscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.mergesubscription.aspx) class.  Please see the section *To synchronize a push subscription to a merge publication* in [How to: Synchronize a Push Subscription (RMO Programming)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146910.aspx).

Comment: I actually did like you said by utilizing MergeSubscription Class and I was getting status updates for the sync operation, but I wanted to get also status updates for sync operations that others might have started ( like syncronization History from Microsoft ).

Comment: After double checking the form that shows synchronization history from Microsoft, it seems that it is doing Manual/Auto refresh, which imply that we can't subscribe to the status event to get notified, and I have to use MergeSubscriberMonitor Class to get information about other sessions, Correct?

Comment: MergeSubscriberMonitor class is for monitoring Merge subscriptions at the Subscriber.  ReplicationMonitor and PublicationMonitor classes can be used to monitor Merge subscriptions at the Distributor.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147926.aspx

Comment: Yes, I am looking to monitor Merge subscriptions at the subscriber & also to allow the user at some cases to initiate the sync ... I checked the link you provided & I think that I have to call GetLastSessionSummary to get Session Info.